# How to prevent stale connections during DROP TABLE?

Tags: mysql

I have a sql script that executes some queries as follows:

```
//LOAD DATA into foo_new;
RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_old, foo_new To foo;
DROP TABLE foo_old;
```

Further, I have a foo_view`that depends on table` foo`.
There are often some long-running (1 min) connections that aggregate data from foo_view.

Question: would I have to delay the `DROP TABLE` for at least 1min, because m̀ysql`might hold references to the old foo table from before the`RENAME` action?

Or does the DROP automatically wait for running queries to finish, before dropping the table?

Comment: I would hope that `RENAME` locks things, but I don't know for sure.